# how to push or pop viewcontroller through delegation?

Tags: iphone

I have rootcontroller with navigation system. what I want to do is pop an old stack and add new stack through delegation. For example, (1) call method contains pop currentview and delegation. (2)in rootview, it receives delegation and push a new stack to it self.

currentviewcontroller.m

```
-(void)chooseSticker:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.delegate returnSetView];
}
```

rootviewcontroller.m

```
-(void) returnSetView{
    SetToolController *setController = [[SetToolController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SetToolController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:setController animated:YES];
    [setController release];

}
```

It only returns to root controller but adding new view. I can find overlapping 'back' button on the navigation bar after I invoke the method.

Comment: Change animated to No or give some delay. Whats the output on the console?

Comment: gosh!! it works!!! thanks alot!!but I only tried animation to NO, how to apply delay in here? thank btw!!

Comment: Ok i am going to add it as an answer. You can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animations are blocking your view to be created. Hence either you can turn off the animations or you can add a delay before displaying the other view.

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject: afterDelay: waitUntilDone:YES
```