# How can I close my current view controller and push another view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to close my current view controller and go to the next page?

i.e close the current view controller and push another view controller on the stack.

I am able to close current page using the below code

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

But opening a new controller just after this is not working.

Comment: Push is not working as self is not there anymore, as you have already popped the self.

Comment: If you are using a navigation controller, just push a new view on the stack.

Comment: Why are you trying to pop then push? If you're going to that then reset the rootViewController. A push implies you want a navigation stack. Popping it means you want to remove the VC from memory. These are fundamentally opposite. If you want to keep a navigation stack, then just don't pop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling push and pop on the self at the same time will not work, as self has already been removed. You need to handle the stack of view controller -

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;

 NSMutableArray *activeViewControllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: navigationController.viewControllers] ;
 [activeViewControllers removeLastObject];

 // Reset the navigation stack
 [navigationController setViewControllers:activeViewControllers];

 [navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Apart from this if you don't want this view controller , when popping from your new view controller, you have other options available.

Like `firstVC` -> `secondVC` -> `thirdVC`

Now from `thirdVC` if you directly want to come to `firstVC` (skipping secondVC, i believe which is why you want both push and pop). Then for this purpose you can use - `popToViewController`.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:firstVC animated:YES];
```

Just checked that there are already couple of questions available on the same topic, you can refer those too for good opinion and answers-

[How can I pop a view from a UINavigationController and replace it with another in one operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410471/how-can-i-pop-a-view-from-a-uinavigationcontroller-and-replace-it-with-another-i)

[popping and pushing view controllers in same action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872852/popping-and-pushing-view-controllers-in-same-action)

[How to pop a viewController and then Push a viewController through delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142779/how-to-pop-a-viewcontroller-and-then-push-a-viewcontroller-through-delegation)

Comment: This may be a good place to do a quick education on the difference between push and pop, and why it doesn't make sense to try to do both

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:firstVC animated:YES];

[CATransaction commit];
```

This will pop to 'firstVC' and push the new viewController as soon as the pop animation is finished.

However, I doubt this behavior will be very user-friendly, because your are popping and pushing right after each other ... very confusing. But if it is suitable in your case, you can sure do it using the above code :)